# ListView is not working for android

Tags: android, listview

So I am reading Commonsware's Android Programming Tutorials and I am stuck with the part where the book asks me to add a ListView. Here is my layout's xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="Name:"/>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/name"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="Address:"/>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/address"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="Type: "/>
                <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:id="@+id/take_out" android:text="Take-Out"/>
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:id="@+id/sit_down" android:text="Sit-Down"/>
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:id="@+id/delivery" android:text="Delivery"/>
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>

            <Button android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        </TableLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/restaurants"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_above="@id/details"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is my activity code

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class LunchList extends Activity {

    List<Restaurant> model = new LinkedList<Restaurant>();
    ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> arrayAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurants);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Restaurant>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }


    private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText addressField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);

            Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
            restaurant.setName(nameField.getText().toString());
            restaurant.setAddress(addressField.getText().toString());


            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.types);

            switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {

                case (R.id.take_out):
                    restaurant.setType("take_out");
                    break;

                case (R.id.sit_down):
                    restaurant.setType("sit_down");
                    break;

                case (R.id.delivery):
                    restaurant.setType("delivery");
                    break;

                case (R.id.korean):
                    restaurant.setType("korean");
                    break;

                case (R.id.chinese):
                    restaurant.setType("chinese");
                    break;

                case (R.id.japanese):
                    restaurant.setType("japanese");
                    break;

                case (R.id.italian):
                    restaurant.setType("italian");
                    break;

                case (R.id.indonesian):
                    restaurant.setType("indonesian");
                    break;

            }

            arrayAdapter.add(restaurant);
            Log.i("LunchList", "Array Adapter Size: " + arrayAdapter.getCount());
        }
    };
}
```

I added a logging line to see whether the object is being added to the adapter or not and it looks like it is being added in there. The UI however is not showing the ListView and I do not see stuff getting added in the list.

Edit XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="Name:"/>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/name"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="Address:"/>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/address"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="Type: "/>
                <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:id="@+id/take_out" android:text="Take-Out"/>
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:id="@+id/sit_down" android:text="Sit-Down"/>
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:id="@+id/delivery" android:text="Delivery"/>
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>

            <Button android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        </TableLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/restaurants"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_above="@id/details"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think you were downvoted because you have included a lot of irrelevant code.  You might consider trimming it.

Comment: Well... I don't even know which part is irrelevant because I don't know where the problem is... I got downvoted last time for trimming too much code...

Comment: heh, yeah it's bad when ppl don't leave comments as to why they downvoted.

Comment: Seriously. Anonymous downvotes are the worst. +1 from me to counter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you initialise model:

```
List<Restaurant> model = new LinkedList<Restaurant>();
```

But don't put any content in it, so there is nothing for your list to show

**EDIT:** If you are adding content to your list dynamically, make sure that you are updating the list like this:

```
model.add(restaurant);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or:

```
arrayAdapter.add(restaurant);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`notifyDataSetChanged()` lets the `ListView` know that the list contents have changed and it should redraw itself

**EDIT:** Also, you are adding the `ListView` above the `TableLayout` called `details`, which has its heigh and width set to `fill_parent`, so you may not see the `ListView` if the `TableLayout` is taking up the whole screen. Try changing the height of `details` to `wrap_content`

Comment: arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Restaurant>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: and I do arrayAdapter.add(restaurant); whenever save is clicked

Comment: I see that you pass model to the ArrayAdapter, but you didn't add any Restaurant objects to model, so the ArrayAdapter is given an empty List

Comment: not to the List directly no, but I add i to the arrayAdapter. arrayAdapter.add(restaurant);

Comment: I changed to model.add(restaurant);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you want this UI to look like? Your ListView says this:

```
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_above="@id/details"
```

So you're basically saying you want your ListView to be above `details`. But `details` is the first element, so that on is presumably on the top of the screen already!

EDIT: I wrote it in a comment, but I should amend my answer: use a LinearLayout instead (vertical orientation, of course), and give each element a weight of 1 (or adjust the weight as you wish). That way, one element can't drown out the other.

Comment: Yes I want it to be ontop of the details but does the XML element position matter in this case?

Comment: Absolutely. RelativeLayout can be a bit finnicky, and I would recommend populating it top-to-bottom.

Comment: so I just moved my ListView before TableLayout and changed android:layout_above="@+id/details" and the table layout's id to android:id="@id/details". Nothing has changed

Comment: make sure the TableLayout's id is android:id="@+id/details", not android:id="@id/details"

Comment: Since you have a Relativelayout with two elements, one over the other, it would make more sense to use a LinearLayout instead and give each one a weight of 1. Keep in mind that "details" has fill_parent, so it'll drown out the ListView without the weight set.

Comment: So is there no way to use RelativeLayout in this case? Thank you guys for the help so far. Please check the updated xml

Comment: There is. RelativeLayout is the big brother of LinearLayout and allows for a lot more flexibility (think GridBagLayout in J2SE), but it can also take more tweaking to set up. In your case, LinearLayout sounds like everything you need. Did you try it? Also, can you get rid of the align_parentLayoutTop? You're basically saying "put this ListView at the same position as the RelativeLayout", which is NOT what you want.